# Duplicate exception error

Tags: purescript

Trying to call `Eff` from within `Aff`:

```
import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff, launchAff)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Class (liftEff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (EXCEPTION)

f :: forall eff. Int -> Aff (exception :: EXCEPTION) String
f i = pure $ show i

g :: forall eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, exception :: EXCEPTION) Unit
g = void $ launchAff do
  s <- f 1
  liftEff $ log s
```

This gets me to duplicate:

```
  Could not match type

    ( exception :: EXCEPTION
    , exception :: EXCEPTION
    )

  with type

    ( console :: CONSOLE
    , exception :: EXCEPTION
    , exception :: EXCEPTION
    )


while trying to match type Eff
                             ( exception :: EXCEPTION
                             , exception :: EXCEPTION
                             )
  with type Eff
              ( console :: CONSOLE
              , exception :: EXCEPTION
              )
while checking that expression (apply void) (launchAff ((bind (...)) (\$0 ->
                                                                        ...
                                                                     )
                                                       )
                                            )
  has type Eff
             ( console :: CONSOLE
             , exception :: EXCEPTION
             )
             Unit
in value declaration g
```

What should I do? Using purescript version 0.11.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the type of `launchAff`, which does not include the `exception` label in its input row. One solution is to include the label twice in the result of `g`:

```
forall eff. Eff ( console :: CONSOLE
                , exception :: EXCEPTION
                , exception :: EXCEPTION
                ) Unit
```

but this means you need to use `catchException` twice outside `launchAff`, which is not very natural.

Another is to remove the label using `catchException` inside the call to `launchAff`.

A third option is to report a bug on the `purescript-aff` repo, and to try to change the type of `launchAff`.